Boot Camp without USB
I have a 2011 Mac mini running macOS 10.13.6. Is possible to use Boot Camp without an USB drive? I was wondering, because it seems a waste to buy a USB just for this.

The Boot Camp Assistant will install UEFI booting Windows 10 without a DVD or USB flash drive on certain newer Intel Macs. Your Mac is not one of them. You may be able to modify the Boot Camp Assistant application to believe your Mac is one of these. However, since your previous question shown your Mac to legacy BIOS boot Windows 8.1, most likely the latest Windows Support Software for your Mac will not contain all (or any) the correct drivers for an UEFI booting Windows. So, if you were to succeed in installing, I would not be surprised if sound did not work properly.

Thanks i will just get a new USB

Or, you could also install without using the Boot Camp Assistant. Also, you might want to consider trying Windows 10 or 11. Neither require a product key to install, but require purchasing a license late to continue use.

Windows 10 or 11 can be used without a license for years, only certain customization features (for example desktop background) will be disabled
